# Evaluate Template Function in MS Visual Studio 2010 Watch Window

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates

Question: Is there any way I can evaluate template function from the MS Visual Studio Watch 2010 Window?

Details: I know that if I have following function:

```
void Test (CString& sSample)
{
   OutputDebugString (_T("The value of Sample is ") + sSample);
}
```

I can use in the Watch Window and have the output printed in the Output Window while debugging. But, I see that this is not working when use a Template function like the below:

```
template<class T>
void Test (T& t)
{
   OutputDebugString (_T("The value when T is string is: ") + t);
}
```

Can I somehow achieve it? I know that autoexp.bat is helpful for variables. But clueless how it behaves for functions. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem debugging template functions. The problem here is with OutputDebugString, its argument is string, so "Text1" + "Text2" doesn't work, "Text1" + 123 doesn't work. It happens to work with CString, otherwise it's not really template material.

This will work with VS 2013 ( in C++ => Language options, enable RTTI ) it may not work with VS 2010:

```
template<class T> void Test2(T& t)
{
    OutputDebugStringA( "typeid(t).name=" );
    OutputDebugStringA( typeid(t).name() );
    OutputDebugStringA( "\n" );
}

int i = 0;
CString str = "str";
Test(i);
Test(str);
```

Anyway, just try make the template function simpler so it works with integers, floats, etc. Or make it distinguish between numbers and strings.

Comment: I couldn't test with MS Visual Studio 2013. But I see that even if we have avoid printing CString in the OutputDebugString, the template function evaluation is not working in 2010.